# Python for loop index, without enumerate

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, time-complexity

Many of us know that, `enumerate` is being using in a situation you use the `for` loop and need to know the index. However, it has its **downsides**. According to my tests with the `timeit` module, just using `enumerate` makes the code 2x slower. Adding this a tuple assignment makes it slower up to 3x. These numbers may come as fast enough for any programmer, but people dealing with algorithms know that every bit of code you can optimize, is a **huge** advantage. Now to my question,

An example of this usage would be, the need of finding indexes of multiple elements in a `list`. Say that there is two elements we need to find. The first two solutions that occur to me is like so:

```
x, y = 0, 0
for ind, val in enumerate(lst):
    if x and y:
        break
    if val == "a":
        x = ind
    elif val == "b":
        y = ind
```

The solution above iterates the list, assign the values, than break if the two is found.

```
x = lst.index("a")
y = lst.index("b")
```

This is an other solution, which I didn't want to use because it appeared really naive. It iterates over the same list twice, to find two elements. The first solution, does this in a single iteration. So by complexity terms, even though we make extra assignments in the first solution, it should be faster than the second one in larger lists. But my assumption **failed**.

**Here is the code I tested the performance:** https://codeshare.io/XfvGA

The second solution was 2x to 10x faster than the first one, changing with the position of these two elements. There are several possibilities which this would occur.

- There is an optimization in `index()` method that I am unaware of.
- Lower level assignments being made in `index()` method. Possible use of C++ code.
- The conditions and extra assignments in the first solution, makes it slower than expected.

Even these reasons fall short of explaining the speed of iterating the list **twice** over iterating it **once**. Though languages have much difference in time while running code, iteration process itself is independant from the programming language, if you need to check a million elements, you still have to check a million elements (Could be exampled by `map()` being not much faster than using a loop to change values).

So though I need you to examine the cases I presented, in order to clarify what is being asked here, question can be put together like this. We know that Python's `for` loop is actually a `while` running in background (possibly in C ?). So this means, the **index** is being stored as it is incremented somewhere in the memory. If there was a way to access it, this would eliminate the cost of calling and unpacking `enumerate`. My question is:

Is there such a way exists ?, If not, could be made (why, or why not) ?

**The sources I used for more information on the subject:**

[Python speed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed)

[Python objects time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

[Performance tips for Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Comment: I see no reason to assume that code which has a single for loop (but which does twice as much work per pass) should be faster than two sequential for loops, each of which does less work per pass. Also, note that your single-loop version only short-circuits after both items has been found. If you were testing against random input, that could explain some of the difference.

Comment: @JohnColeman Of course the work done in the loops decides the performance. Yet in theory, the work these loops do, could be equal (Maybe not in Python, but as pseudocode) and the single iteration faster.

Comment: Your assertion that there is an **index** stored somewhere in memory for every `for` loop is also wrong. The iterator protocol just has to return a value or raise a `StopIteration` exception when `next()` is called, it is explicitly free from the requirement to maintain an index in a list. That's why `enumerate` exists, to simulate that feature of stepping over a fixed list when required.

Comment: @ToreEschliman I did not know that index was not stored. Thanks, this changes my view on the subject of course. By the way, I would appreciate whoever downvoted, explained why.

Comment: "...but people dealing with algorithms know that every bit of code you can optimize, is a **huge** advantage" is patently untrue. See [_When to optimize_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: @martineau But I am not discussing premature optimization. If I had found the method that I am seeking in this question, it would help me in some of my problems, which would be considered a real optimization. The fact that, what I am looking for does not exist in Python, does not make it an unnecessary optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that the `enumerate` is the problem, to prove this you can do:

```
x, y = 0, 0
for val in a:
    if x and y:
        break
    if val == "a":
        x = val
    elif val == "b":
        y = val
```

This doesnt do the same thing you wanted in the first place (you dont get the index) but if you messure it with timeit, you will find that the diffrence is not so significant, meaning that the `enumerate` is not the source of the problem ( in my case it was 0.185 to 0.155 when running your example, so it is faster but the second solution got 0.055 at my computer )

The reason that `lst.index` is faster is that it is implemented in C .

You can see it's source code here:
https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c
the index function is called `listindex` in this file and is defined like

`static PyObject *
listindex(PyListObject *self, PyObject *args)`
( i couldnt find a way to add a link directly to the function )

Comment: You are correct, however it does not change that if we needed to find multiple indexes, we still need to iterate over the list more than once. Which is an overkill, no matter what language you use.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to be un-Pythonic, which isn't going to end terribly well for you. If you really need to have that iterator count information available, there is a well-known and optimized way to do that: `enumerate()`. If you need to find an item in a list, there is a well-known and optimized way to do that: `lst.index()`. As DorElias showed above/below, `enumerate` is not the problem, it's that you're attempting to reinvent the wheel with the rest of your `for` loop. `enumerate` is going to be the best-supported (clearest, fastest, etc.) way to maintain an iteration count in every situation *where an iteration count is actually the thing you need*.

Comment: The wheel is re-invented, just to visualize what is being asked, to find if a similar behavior is appliable in Python terms. Except that, I agree with you.